# Coldfusion Decrypt Crash - An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: ''

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, cryptography

I have been seeing a lot of problems and resolutions of Coldfusion Decrypt function.  However, I have not come across this one at all.

I can encrypt and decrypt properly. I generated a key and encrypt it with:

```
<cfset encrytedpwd = encrypt(password, mykey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
```

This is done in program #1.  Then in a different program #2 I decrypted it with:

```
<cfset mypwd = decrypt(encrytedpwd, mykey, AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
```

which is great and works perfectly.

Now the problem: the password for all the records are not always encrypted.  Some are encrypted because they passed thru program #1.  But some old records are not encrypted.  So when the password is retrieved as "encrytedpwd", the decrypt function will crash with the error:

**An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: ''.**

I would expect the CF Decrypt function to return maybe "false" or some kind of warning rather than cause the CF to crash.

Another scenario is that if someone temper with the value of the encrypted password before passing to program #2, it will also crash.

Is there any way to check the value of password that it is hex or not before passing to the Decrypt function so that it won't crash ungracefully?

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:**

I added the try/catch in the code and it does not catch the exception at all.

On top of the CF activate.cfm I include a template call handlerror.cfm which has the following:

```
<cferror
    template = "exception.cfm"
    type = "exception"
    mailTo = "webmaster@mydomain.com">
```

The exception.cfm is simply a formatted error page:

```
...
<li><b>Your Location:</b> #error.remoteAddress#
<li><b>Your Browser:</b> #error.browser#
<li><b>Date and Time the Error Occurred:</b> #error.dateTime#
<li><b>Page You Came From:</b> #error.HTTPReferer#
<li><b>Message Content</b>:
<p>#error.diagnostics#</p> 
...
```

The activate.cfm has

```
<cfinclude template="handlerror.cfm">
<cfif isdefined("url.chk") and isdefined("url.auth")>
    <cfif len(url.chk) gt 0 and len(url.auth) gt 0>
        <cftry>
        <cfset uid=decrypt(url.chk, mykey, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "hex")>
            <cfcatch>
                <div class="msgcenter">
                <div class="warning">Sorry, there seems to be an issue with the activation </div><br>
                </div>
                <cfoutput>
                <!--- The diagnostic message from ColdFusion. --->
                <p>#cfcatch.message#</p>
                <p>Caught an exception, type = #CFCATCH.TYPE#</p>
                <p>The contents of the tag stack are:</p>
                <cfdump var="#cfcatch.tagcontext#">
                </cfoutput>
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>
        <cfif REFindNoCase("[^a-z0-9_]", uid)>
            <div class="warning">Problem with User ID.</div><br>
        <cfelse>
.....
```

So what is happening now is, if the url.chk is tempered or invalid, it goes to display the exception but for the undefined UID for the REFindNoCase because the Decrypt didn't work in the first place and now it is skipping it because of try/catch.

Without the try/catch the exception would show the error message "*An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input string: ''.*"  But because of the try/catch it is not doing that now.  So I am stuck.

Comment: At a minimum you can wrap it in a try catch

Comment: *so that it won't crash ungracefully?* Even if the input is hex, there is no guarantee it will decrypt with your key. In short, there is no warning feature of decrypt. Either it works, or throws an exception that you must handle. If you really cannot make the values uniform, then as Matt suggested, wrap it in a try/catch. Though, passwords should be *hashed* - not encrypted.

Comment: The values can be uniform.  But of course encryption is to prevent people from tempering.  But if they do, CF shouldn't be throwing exception just because it can't decrypt.  Why password should be hashed not encrypted?

Comment: BTW, I try the CFTRY and CFCATCH and they don't work.  I have generic page with CFERROR that display the exceptions.  It went there instead AND bypass the Decrypt exception. It did not display the message I set within the CFCATCH.

Comment: *CF shouldn't be throwing exception just because it can't decrypt.* Yes, it should because that is how the function is designed. It either decrypts successfully or throws an exception. Wanting it to behave differently isn't going to change the behavior of the function ;) Try/catch works fine. (Though consider switching to Application.cfc/onError instead of cferror). If it is not working for you, then you are doing something different on your end. You need to post a repro case.

Comment: @Leigh I wish Adobe would do that. That would save a lot of headaches. I have never used an Application.cfc before.  Can you help provide a good simple and basic Application.cfc example to use?  Since Decryt isn't "working" the way I like, I think I need to handle it with the error handling in CF somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping in a try/catch block worked for me in both Railo and CF. I see that you're using a `<cferror>` page, but if that is indeed interfering, you can run this code once outside the application so that the try/catch will engage or temporarily disable the cferror.

Because of your CFERROR, I would run a script across your table as below, update the non-encrypted users with a flag field. Then you can either

1. Run a script to automatically encrypt their data and set the prior-mentioned flag to false.
2. The more responsible thing, since their data wasn't encrypted, would be to require them to change their password, encrypt the new value, and then set the flag to false.

Code:

```
<cfset PlainPWsList = "">
<cfoutput><cfloop query="CheckPWs">
  encrypted password: #i#<br/>
  <cftry><cfset AttemptDecrypt = Decrypt(password...)>
    <cfcatch type="any"><cfset PlainPWsList = ListAppend(PlainPWsList,userID)><!--- This password wasn't encrypted ---></cfcatch></cftry><br><br>
  </cfloop>
  </cfoutput>

<cfquery>
update users
  set forcepwchange = 1
 where userID in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PlainPWsList#" list="yes">)
</cfquery>
```

And then, when the user logs in, you can make a decision based on the value of the flag. You could even do that entirely in the query.

```
select userid,stuff from users
 where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
   and ((password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#encrypt(form.password)#"> and forcepwchange = 0) or (password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.password#"> and forcepwchange = 1))
```

Now, as Leigh brought up: **Why aren't you hashing your passwords?**. The only almost-justifiable "use" for not hashing your passwords is password recovery and really, allowing the user a reset-route is much better. Encryption/decryption otherwise only allows staff members or prying eyes to see the passwords. Even if you've designed a system where admin can login to user accounts for customer service purposes, a secondary gateway can be written so that the admin doesn't need to know the user password.

Here's what I'd do.. I'd step up the flag.

0 = Password is hashed and fine. While salting hashes is a great thing, there's no real need to encrypt and then hash. On your change password page that users from either list arrive at, I'd just salt and hash the data. Salt because there are tables of straight hashes of entire dictionaries (and given people's penchant for the simplest passswords possible, this is important to help them avoid).

1 = Password is encrypted and needs hashed.

2 = Password is plain text and needs hashed.

```
<cfset PlainPWsList = "">
<cfset EncryptedPWsList = "">
<cfoutput><cfloop query="CheckPWs">
  encrypted password: #i#<br/>
  <cftry><cfset AttemptDecrypt = Decrypt(password...)>
    <cfset EncryptedPWsList=ListAppend(EncryptedPWsList,userID)>
    <cfcatch type="any"><cfset PlainPWsList = ListAppend(PlainPWsList,userID)><!--- This password wasn't encrypted ---></cfcatch></cftry><br><br>
  </cfloop>
  </cfoutput>


<cfquery>
update users
  set forcepwchange = 2
 where userID in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#PlainPWsList#" list="yes">)
</cfquery>


<cfquery>
update users
  set forcepwchange = 1
 where userID in (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#EncryptedPWsList#" list="yes">)
</cfquery>
```

And then your login query

```
select userid,stuff from users
 where username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.username#">
   and ((password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#hash(saltedpassword)#"> and forcepwchange = 0) 
    or (password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#encrypt(form.password)#"> and forcepwchange = 1)
    or (password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.password#"> and forcepwchange = 2))
```

Comment: I suspect they are just using it incorrectly. The point of try/catch is to allow more granular error handling. If a higher level handler like cferror interfered with that, it would defeat the purpose. The cferror handler should only kick in if the code is *not* handling the exception with a try/catch OR if the code throws an Error (that is different than an Exception).

Comment: (I'm sure you know all that already. The explanation was primarily for the OP).

Comment: @Leigh I agree. A mismanaged invocation of cftry probably caused its own error and threw our friend to his error page. Happens.

Comment: On top of every CF program, I cfinclude a template which has CFERROR calling an formatted exception template which tells the users what the exception is. I put try and catch in the program in the middle of of the program to decrypt.  When the exception occurred (can be due to tempering) the exception is not being handled by the try/catch.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me. Rather than describing the code, it would help cut to the chase faster if you just *showed* us the code :) Please update your question with a *small* example that demonstrates "the exception not being handled by the try/catch". Also, I am not sure what you mean by "program", but `cferror` is generally included (once) in your Application.cfm file. Though cferror was generally replaced by `onError` in Application.cfc.

Comment: @Leigh  I have edited the question.  I don't have an Application.cfc so I include it on every templates.  Program means template. I am used to do programming.  CF is actually programming :)

Comment: @Jack Okay, the reason the cftry/catch isn't working is because you are `try`ing to set the variable, and then after that, outside of the try/catch, you're attempting to access the variable. For instance, place a `<cfparam name="uid" default="">` at the top of the page, and your error may well vanish. It may not work perfectly yet. You'll probably also want to alter your `cfif` to `<cfif len(trim(uid)) and REFindNoCase("[^a-z0-9_]", uid)>`

Comment: @cfqueryparam it worked!  Thank you. Thanks Leigh also.  Should I be adding a Application.cfc?  If yes, what should I have it there given that I have the exception.cfm when CFERROR occur? I don't see the need to use sessiontimeout, applicationtimeout as they are already set in CF admin.  How can I log the user out if there is no activities say 10 minutes after they login?

Comment: @Jack, new questions should be posed separately as their own questions. However, you can google for a comparison between the two App files. (.cfm is still capable, but .cfc is superior and supports a few things that Application.cfm does not.) As to your timeout question, google sessiontimeout.

Comment: @Jack - "*Program means template*". Ah, okay. The term "program" tends to make me think of an .exe or something consisting of a collection of files (ie multiple). So I was not sure if that meant you were including `cferror` in your Application.cfc/cfm`, or within each individual .cfm script (less common).

Comment: @Leigh I don't have an Application.cfc  Never used one and not sure if I need one.

Comment: *Technically* it depends on your application. But I think most folks use them. (At the very least for session/application variables). Since the Application.cfc/cfm automatically runs before every CF request, it makes certain tasks easier. For example, if you were using an application file you would not need to embed `<cferror>` in every one of your .cfm scripts. You could put that logic in your application file, and it would be applied to all of your app's files.

Comment: @Leigh So it doesn't matter which directory or subdirectory the error occurs, the Application.cfc error will handle it?  I just encountered an issue.  The original password is case sensitive with upper and lower case, after the encryption and decryption to match the user input, the case-sensitivity is gone.  The user can enter either lower or upper and it will match!  How to fix this?

Comment: @Jack Dipping in for a sec. Application.cfc (and .cfm) will handle all files in its own directory and any subdirectory that doesn't contain an Application file. Any "branch" that does becomes the application page responsible for the hierarchy below that. Custom tags, includes, services* use the application.cfc/m based on the *requested page's* location. However, remote calls like ajax requests, cfhttp's, etc use the application file responsible for the page called, because they are essentially browser requests. Your App file is literally the core of your application.

Comment: @cfqueryparam  Thanks for your guidance.  So I am basically running without a core :(  I think I may have found a CF 9 bug.  When CFERROR type is set to "request", the error page thrown out contains CF codes on browser!  This is pretty bad.  It doesn't happen if the type is set to "exception".  Are you aware of this?

Comment: @Jack - What you are seeing is not a bug. As noted in the `cferror` docs - and on your other thread - you cannot include CFML tags in `cferror type="request"`. The docs on [error handling are pretty comprehensive](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0bb9b-7fe0.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d1d). You should probably spend some time reading those to get a better understanding of how to implement error handling in an application file.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned earlier, `Application.cfm` and `cferror` were superceded by `Application.cfc` and the `onError` method. Do a search for "Application.cfc sample". There are a bunch of articles/examples and explanations of the Application.cfc file, such as http://learncfinaweek.com/week1/Application_cfc/

Comment: @Jack - Also, please review [The Quick Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Stack Overflow is not like a discussion forum. It is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site: only one question per thread. "Comments" are considered temporary. (In fact long threads like this are often deleted.) So if you have a different question/problem it is better to open a separate question, so the information is preserved and available to others that run into the same problem.